# How to put three divs in the same line with css?

Tags: html, css

How to put three divs on the same line using css?

```
 <div style="width: 100%; height: 30%; background-color: aqua; padding: 0; margin: 0">
            <div style="height: 30%; width: 20%; background-color: #ffd800; margin-left: 0%;padding:0;margin-top:0">
                <%--left--%>
            </div>
            <div style="height: 30%; width: 60%; background-color: #4cff00; margin-left: 20%;padding:0;margin-top:0">
               <%--center--%>
            </div>
            <div style="height: 30%; width: 20%; background-color: #ffd800; margin-left: 80%;padding:0;margin-top:0">
                <%--right--%>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `<%--left--%>` is invalid. HTML comments are like `<!--comment-->`.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

You can use `display: flex;` and there won't be any white space

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/ctnrwn1x/1/)

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.box {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}
#center {
    background-color: green;
    width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <%--left--%>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="center">
        <%--center--%>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <%--right--%>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It won't work since 1. there are margins, 2. total width is exactly 100% and there are whitespaces between `div` elements in HTML.

Comment: @panther the whitespace is from your HTML source. Remove whitespace between `</div>` and `<div>`

Comment: @LB--: I know how it works, but: 1. answer doesn't tells it, 2. it isn't obvious from that, 3. code without indenting code block is bad readable. It isn't the good practise. Better is to use float in this case.

Comment: @AramilRey: you changed `inline-block` solution with almost 100% of browser support (just with bad/uncomplete comment) for `flex` with support IE10+. Strange, why to do that simply if it's possible with worse browser support :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all inline styles (except widths) and use simply:

```
<style>
    div {overflow: hidden}
    div > div {float: left;}

    /* remove these lines, just for test */
    div > div {background: yellow}
    div + div {background: green}
    div + div + div {background: red}
</style>

<div>
    <div style="width: 20%;">
        <%--left--%>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 60%;">
        <%--center--%>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 20%;">
        <%--right--%>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qukpcq8f/

I've left `width`s as inline styles, I mean it's easier to you to understand. You should move them into external styles.